# Blank spaces in header read csv

Tags: r, csv

I want to read a file with **read.csv2** function. This file contains blank spaces in column names. Whith the parameter header = FALSE I can read the file but when I replace FALSE by TRUE, I have this error :

```
Error in make.names(col.names, unique = TRUE) : chaîne de charactères multioctets incorrecte 7
```

How can I manage this error?

My code :

```
client <- read.csv2("./data/Clients.csv", header = T, na.strings = "",
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE, sep = ";", encoding = "UTF-8")
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: With `read.csv2` you don't need `header = TRUE` nor `sep = ";"`, these are the defaults. I have just tried reading a file with spaces in the colnames with `read.csv2("teste.CSV", fill = TRUE)` and with `read.csv2("teste.CSV", fill = TRUE, check.names = FALSE)`. Both work, the first replaces the spaces with dots.

Comment: Could you give us some reproducible example of the data you're trying to read?

Comment: I suspect your question is more about *"how to keep the spaces"* vice *"how to read"*, since it does not produce an error or warning. Try: `read.csv2(..., check.names=FALSE)`.

Comment: Try fileEncoding="CP1252" .. it solve my problem (using a file creating by Windows in my Linux OS)

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is pointing towards column name having a multi-bytes character which is not compatible with `UTF-8`.

An option is to use  `encoding = "UCS-2LE"`:

```
client <- read.csv2("./data/Clients.csv", header = TRUE, na.strings = "",
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE, sep = ";", encoding = "UCS-2LE")
```